# phpMyAdmin replication

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, database-replication

Am trying to set up replication between two servers but keep getting the following error[image]

Full Query says:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci';
```

Both master and slave database have collation set as utf8_general_ci.

Any ideas?

Comment: It would have been nice to see the **entire** query

Comment: All databases, tables **and** columns use `utf8_general_ci`?

Comment: Could you post the full error?

Comment: added full error in edit. Doesn't show that much extra

Comment: When and how are you getting this error?  What are you doing *before* the error happens?  Poking around with charsets isn't part of setting up replication...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help. In the end just uninstalled MySQL and installed an earlier version. They seem to be talking to each other now.

Answer (score 1):

please, check if in the destination server you have that collation and charset available. 
You can do it with

```
SHOW CHARACTER SET
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-character-set.html

and

```
SHOW COLLATION
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-collation.html

Comment: The Master server has an older version on MySQL, which doesn't have utfmb4 and I don't want to upgrade it as it's already used for replication with an existing server and don't want to break that. Is there a way I can tell the new slave to disregard utf8mb4?

Comment: How are you doing the replication?with a sql dump? You will do it one time or it will br automated?

Comment: Am trying to set it up through phpMyAdmin to be automated to run on a regular basis.

Comment: Have set all charset references to match those of the master. The only difference is the session charsets still say utf8mb4, even after restarting the session. Coul this be the cause of the problem? Is there any way to change this?

Comment: in your server dhasboard (click on server, on the top of phpmyadmin) what do you have under "MySQL connection collation"?  you can change it there on both servers, and also run 
mysql> SET character_set_client = x;
mysql> SET character_set_results = x;
mysql> SET collation_connection = @@collation_database; on both servers

Comment: also, check http://makandracards.com/makandra/2529-show-and-change-mysql-default-character-set to see the many different parts where charset could be different